# passing simpleXML Object across Pages

Tags: php, xml, xml-serialization, simplexml, joomla-extensions

I am using simpleXML objects with the commission junction Commission Details API. It is working properly and I am getting the commission details. Now I am displaying the report in one page and upon presssing the 'Add Report' button it has to be added to the DB. But I am not able to pass the simpleXML Object variable across the pages. I have tried to pass it as a hidden value after serialing it . But there is some issues with serialization of simpleXML Object and so I cannot use it. Please let me know how can I pass the value to other page. I mean how can I POST the object. I am using this inside a custom Joomla component.

Comment: How about using session to store data?

Comment: @Xupypr MV: since session will serilize the object he should have the same issue as he does with directly calling serialize/unserialize.

Comment: @ prodigitalson I have tried to pass the variable as a hidden field. But it is passing the '?xml version=' only. This is how I am passing the variable.  [code]( $report_xml=$reports->asXML();<input type="hidden" name="report" value="<?php echo $report_xml; ?>">).  and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since XML is essentially a data interchange formmay why dont you just save it out as an xml string again with `$xml->asXML()` and post that?